# Why do I getting "TypeError: Value is undefined and could not be converted to an object" in Qt QML?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qml, pyside2

I have made a simple listview in Qt Qml. I am using PySide2 and QStringListModel to populate the listview. When the list is larger like in this simple example, clicking by the printBtn(which should change the text color to green) in Qt Qml getting the following error: "**TypeError: Value is undefined and could not be converted to an object**" If the list contains less elements, it seems to be fine. How to alter my code to not have this issue in the future.

Is it a bug maybe in Qt? Are there any workaround?

See my simple code snippet below:

**Python:**

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QStringListModel, QObject, Signal, Slot
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

class Main(QObject):

    clicked = Signal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)

    @Slot()
    def justClicking(self):
        self.clicked.emit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    main = Main()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("main", main)

    data = ["London", "New York", "Paris", "Tokyo", "Sydney", "Madrid", "Mumbai", "Istanbul", "Bangkok", "Moscow", "Toronto", "Rome", "Shanghai", "Rio de Janeiro", "Seoul", "Berlin", "Cape Town", "Amsterdam", "Los Angeles", "San Francisco", "Cairo", "Barcelona", "Buenos Aires", "Melbourne", "Athens", "Vancouver", "Dubai", "Prague", "Edinburgh", "Singapore"]

    model = QStringListModel()
    model.setStringList(data)

    context = engine.rootContext()
    context.setContextProperty("myModel", model)

    engine.load("main.qml")
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Qml code:**

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    visible: true
    color: "#161515"
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Listview Example")

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        x: 51
        y: 63
        width: 539
        height: 143
        color: "#ffffff"

        ListView {
            id: listView
            anchors.fill: parent
            model: myModel
            currentIndex: 0
            delegate: Rectangle {
                id: dlg
                width: listView.width
                height: 25
                color: index === listView.currentIndex ? "lightgrey" : "#00000000"
                radius: 10

                property alias colorOfText: titleText.color

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        listView.currentIndex = index
                    }
                }
                Text {
                    id: titleText
                    text: model.display
                    font.pixelSize: 18
                    color: "black"
                    padding: 5
                }
                Connections {
                    target: main
                    function onClicked() {
                        var myListItemObjectC = listView.contentItem.children[listView.currentIndex]
                        myListItemObjectC.colorOfText = "green"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Button {
        id: printBtn
        x: 286
        y: 241
        width: 69
        height: 35
        text: qsTr("Print")
        onClicked: {
            main.justClicking()
        }
    }
}
```

I've been trying to not use QStringListModel, tried to append them to a ListModel, without any luck. I appreciate all help!

Comment: I ported your app to pyside6 and it appears to work.

Comment: May you share your code? @StephenQuan

Comment: I have ported also to PySide6 and it is not working, facing the same issue still.

Comment: I ran it on Ubuntu with pyside6 / Qt6.4.0 and on macOS with pyside6 / Qt6.5.0. I posted my code as an answer, but, I am embarrassed since, the code is actually your code with nothing more than very minor changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ported your app to PySide6. It appears to work with minimal code changes.

Here's `main.py` with PySide2 references changed to PySide6:

```py
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QStringListModel, QObject, Signal, Slot
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

class Main(QObject):

    clicked = Signal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)

    @Slot()
    def justClicking(self):
        self.clicked.emit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    main = Main()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("main", main)

    data = ["London", "New York", "Paris", "Tokyo", "Sydney", "Madrid", "Mumbai", "Istanbul", "Bangkok", "Moscow", "Toronto", "Rome", "Shanghai", "Rio de Janeiro", "Seoul", "Berlin", "Cape Town", "Amsterdam", "Los Angeles", "San Francisco", "Cairo", "Barcelona", "Buenos Aires", "Melbourne", "Athens", "Vancouver", "Dubai", "Prague", "Edinburgh", "Singapore"]

    model = QStringListModel()
    model.setStringList(data)

    context = engine.rootContext()
    context.setContextProperty("myModel", model)

    engine.load("main.qml")
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

<strike>Here's the `main.qml` with the Qt5 imports replaced with Qt6 imports:</strike>

I reworked your `main.qml` to maintain a list of "greened" items. We need to do this, because you cannot access the delegates directly since Qt will create and destroy delegates on demand. We need to rely on the delegates that are visible and that they are property bound to something that we can show.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Window

Window {
    visible: true
    color: "#161515"
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Listview Example")

    property list<string> green

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        x: 51
        y: 63
        width: 539
        height: 143
        color: "#ffffff"

        ListView {
            id: listView
            anchors.fill: parent
            model: myModel
            currentIndex: 0
            delegate: Rectangle {
                id: dlg
                width: listView.width
                height: 25
                color: index === listView.currentIndex ? "lightgrey" : "#00000000"
                radius: 10
                property var modelText: model.display

                property alias colorOfText: titleText.color

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        listView.currentIndex = index
                    }
                }
                Text {
                    id: titleText
                    text: modelText
                    font.pixelSize: 18
                    color: green.indexOf(modelText) !== -1 ? "green" : "black"
                    padding: 5
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Button {
        id: printBtn
        x: 286
        y: 241
        width: 69
        height: 35
        text: qsTr("Print")
        onClicked: {
            main.justClicking()
        }
    }
    Connections {
        target: main
        function onClicked() {
            if (green.indexOf(listView.currentItem.modelText) === -1) {
                green.push(listView.currentItem.modelText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To further understand the lifecycle of your delegates, consider adding the following code to your delegate:

```
                Component.onCompleted: console.log(`Construction for ${model.display} ${index}`);
                Component.onDestruction: console.log(`Destruction for ${model.display} ${index}`);
```

Then, as you scroll your ListView up and down you'll see delegates being created and destroyed. This is the reason why you cannot programmatically access your delegates since they may or may not exist.

Here's a screenshot of your app running:

[image: pyside6-screenshot.png]

Comment: Hi! Well if you choose the last element "Singapore" and you click on the "Print" button don't you get "TypeError: Value is undefined and could not be converted to an object" error message in the console and the "Singapore" text will not turn to green? @Stephen Quan

Comment: Now that I understand your `main.qml` I rewrote a portion of it. See the updated `main.qml` and the corresponding explanation.